# Time complexity of custom graph flow algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, graph-theory

I need to know what's the complexity of the following graph algorithm and how did you manage to find it:

R = (G, s, t, c) be transportation network such that

- G − t is a tree rooted in s (the arcs are oriented away from the root),
- the only incident arcs with t in this network are those coming from the leaves of G − t

Consider the following recursive function where A(u) is the list of out-neighbors of vertex u and initially x is the null flow.

```
 Flow(u, α)
   if ((v ← next[A(u)]) == NULL) then
      return α;
   flowOut ← 0;
   for ((v ← next[A(u)]) 6= NULL) do
      if (α > 0) then
         x[uv] ← Flow(v, min {c[uv], α});
         flowOut ← flowOut + x[uv];
         α ← α − x[uv];
      else
         break;
   return flowOut;
```

Also is this graph a known one so I can search more about it on the internet?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's basically DFS, so linear time. It reminds me of algorithms that compute a blocking flow.